# golang ,strange error around braces or return

Tags: go

```
func isPrimeNumber(possiblePrime int) bool {
    for underPrime := 2; underPrime < possiblePrime; underPrime++ {
        if possiblePrime%underPrime == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}


func findPrimeNumbers(channel chan int) {
    for i := 2; ; /* infinite loop */ i++ {
        // your code goes here
        if isPrimeNumber(i){
            chan <- i     <========error on this line
        }
        assert(i < 100) // i is afraid of heights
    }
}
```

I got error on this but could not figure it out, need help. thanks

syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline, expecting {
FAIL

Comment: do you need a space before the open curly brace of the `if isPrimeNumber(i){`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `channel <- i` instead of `chan <- i`.

In you function definition (`channel chan int`), `channel` is parameter's name, and `chan int` is the type. To clarify, your function could be rewrote to the following one:

```
func findPrimeNumbers(primeNumberChannel chan int) {
    for i := 2; ; i++ {
        if isPrimeNumber(i){
            primeNumberChannel <- i  
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, `assert` is not available in Go (http://golang.org/doc/faq#assertions).